# mysqli failing to load

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

When I run a php script from command line, the mysqli module loads and works, but when I try to run the same php script from Apache, I am having no luck.  Here's what I've done:

1) Uncommented the following line in `php.ini`

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll  ;uncommented--should load
```

2) Updated my extension location in `php.ini

```
extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"
```

3) Updated the location of the `php.ini` file in Apache's `httpd.conf`

```
PHPIniDir “C:/php”
```

4) Restart Apache

I've tried a few variants of this process, but every time I run the php script (looking through the network tab on chrome debugger) I get the following result:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in 
C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\WebAPI\database.php:61
```

When I run the same php code from cmd, I do not get this error.  I'm running php 7.1.5 with Apache 2.4.25 and MySQL 5.7 on windows 10.

**EDIT:**

As far as my code goes, I fail at the very start, calling the following function:

```
function open_database()
{
    if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
        echo('We don\'t have mysqli!!!');
    } else {
        echo('Phew we have it!');
    }
    $dbinfo = get_dbinfo();
    if ($dbinfo == null) return null;
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbinfo[0], $dbinfo[1], $dbinfo[2]);
    return $db;
}
```

Output for CMD:

```
 Phew we have it!
```

Output for Apache:

```
We don't have mysqli!!!<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in 
 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\WebAPI\database.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\WebAPI\visitor_counts.php(116): open_database()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Apache24\htdocs\mysite\WebAPI\database.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
```

Running `phpinfo()` I can only find one line with mysqli in it.  Here's a picture of what I see:

[image]

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  I have attached an image to the question of what I see when I run php info.  I get a single hit when I search mysqli, as you will see in my screenshot.

Comment: What is the code you're trying to execute?  Is this possibly a matter of `mysqli` being in the root namespace while you're calling it elsewhere without `\mysqli`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski,  I'm not sure what you mean.  I've included my code in the question if that helps.

Comment: Verify that the php.ini you modified is the same one pointed to by the line in phpinfo() that says something like `Loaded Configuration File`.  Working in CLI while not in Apache is usually an indication that 2 different .ini files are being loaded. You should see more than just one line of output for mysqli in the `phpinfo()` output too.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski In terms of Loaded Configuration file, I found the issue -- no configuration file loaded.  The weird part, it's looking in C:\Windows not c:\php. I should be able to figure it out from here, but please share your insights in the chance that I have difficulty figuring it out.

Comment: It's been many years since I ran PHP on Windows but the official docs give a good list of ordered search locations for php.ini. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php  One of these may be set for your install, relative to where the PHP dll file is located and used by Apache.

Comment: On further digging, I've found that i need `<VirtualHost>` tags around `PHPIniDir`, but I'm not completely sure which ip address to give as an argument.

Comment: Probably use the address specified in Apache's `Listen` directive. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost  or `_default_`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It wasn't really working, so I just moved php.ini to c:\windows.  that did the trick. Thank you for your help!